# UITableview with multiple rows and sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, for-loop

I have `timeSlotArr` which contains data in the form of given.

```
     timeSlotArr ++++++++ (
        {
        availablenow = 0;
        callbackSlotId = "96a8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
        callbackSlotName = "07:00 AM";
        date = "2016-12-21";
        dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T01:30:00Z";
        day = Wednesday;
    },
        {
        availablenow = 0;
        callbackSlotId = "9aa8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
        callbackSlotName = "09:00 AM";
        date = "2016-12-21";
        dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T03:30:00Z";
        day = Wednesday;
    },
        {
        availablenow = 0;
        callbackSlotId = "9ca8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
        callbackSlotName = "10:00 AM";
        date = "2016-12-21";
        dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T04:30:00Z";
        day = Wednesday;
    }
)
```

I want to display my data in `UITableView` multiple sections and multiple rows inside it.

no of sections are decided based on "day" key(`sections` is array) and `elementsInSection` are the data inside sections

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in timeSlotArr) {
    NSString *day = [dict objectForKey:@"day"];
    if (![sections containsObject:day]) {
        [sections addObject:day];

        NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arr addObject:dict];

        [elementsInSection addObject:arr];
    } else {
        NSMutableArray *arr = [elementsInSection objectAtIndex:[sections indexOfObject:day]];
        [arr addObject:dict];

        [elementsInSection setObject:arr atIndexedSubscript:[sections indexOfObject:day]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"elementsInSection ++++++++ %@",elementsInSection);
elementsInSection Returns 1 instead of 3 here is wrong... 3 means data of `timeSlotArr` with key `day`

NSLog(@"sections ++++++++ %@",sections); //Returns 1 which is right
```

Comment: remove this line and try: [elementsInSection setObject:arr atIndexedSubscript:[sections indexOfObject:day]];

Comment: How do i add to element to `elementsInSection`

Comment: You are already using that array reference  NSMutableArray *arr = [elementsInSection objectAtIndex:[sections indexOfObject:day]]; and adding element. Check how many elements there in arr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my experience you can achieve above sections and row structure in your table view by filtering your data like below:

**Step 1: What you need in sections is `Day`.**
so we will get all unique days from your array.

```
NSArray *uniqueDays = [arrayData valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.day"];
```

**Unique Days Result :**

```
(
    Wednesday,
    Monday,
    Tuesday
)
```

Step 2: Now we need day wise array contains only that day data array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictData1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSString *strDay in uniqueDays) {
     NSArray *filteredDay = [arrayData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(day == %@)", strDay]];
     [dictData1 setObject:filteredDay forKey:strDay];
}
```

**Filtered Data Result :**

```
{
    Monday =     (
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "9ca8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "10:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T04:30:00Z";
            day = Monday;
        },
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "9ca8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "10:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T04:30:00Z";
            day = Monday;
        }
    );
    Tuesday =     (
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "9ca8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "10:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T04:30:00Z";
            day = Tuesday;
        }
    );
    Wednesday =     (
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "96a8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "07:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T01:30:00Z";
            day = Wednesday;
        },
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "9aa8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "09:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T03:30:00Z";
            day = Wednesday;
        },
                {
            availablenow = 0;
            callbackSlotId = "9ca8a387-a2a1-e611-8101-000c29821561";
            callbackSlotName = "10:00 AM";
            date = "2016-12-21";
            dateInUtc = "2016-12-21T04:30:00Z";
            day = Wednesday;
        }
    );
}
```

Now you can use **Unique Days** as `section` `array`.

And `dictData` dictionary as row array and fetch data based on section.

**Edit :** *now use above filter array in table view methods*

```
#pragma mark --- UITableView DataSource methods

//Section
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return uniqueDays.count;
}

//Row
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [[dictData1 objectForKey:uniqueDays[section]] count];
}

//Cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *arrDayData = [dictData1 objectForKey:uniqueDays [indexPath.section]];
    NSDictionary *dictDetail = arrDayData[indexPath.row];

    aCell.textLabel.text = dictDetail[@"callbackSlotId"];

    return aCell;
}
```

Let me know if you required any thing else.

Comment: how do i display for `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: just need to pass day array count in your `numberOfRowsInSection` and same you can use it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Please check my updated answer you can get idea how to show `section` , `row` & `cell`